# how to read a json in angularjs, assign it to variable and work on the variable

Tags: angularjs, json, asynchronous

```
main.js

var myFarm = $http.get('farmList.JSON').success(function(data) {
        $scope.farms= data;
    });
```

var myFarm = $scope.farms;

```
var updateFarms =   function(){
for (i = 1; i <= myFarm.length; i++)
            { 
               // code to update farms
                var sFarm = myFarm[i - 1];
                //loop thru myFarm and update it
                $scope.farms = myFarm; //assign updated farms back to farms 
            }
}

farmList.json
[
        {"farmName": "A", "type": "B"},
        {"farmName": "C", "type": "D"}
]
```

I wanna be able to get the json into a variable so that I can keep a copy. if farms are updated, I should be able to go update myFarm to a new one. how do I get to work with variable in asynchronous func like http.get?

Comment: Don't you just want to do `$scope.farms = data;` instead of `return data;` (which does nothing).

Comment: did it, then it says farms.length on undefined error

Comment: When are you calling `updateFarms`? Also, you will need to change `myFarm` to make it work further.

Comment: update Farms updates type of the farm, so I'd loop thru it and update my Farm eventually because then I know I have a base that I read from the Json and later I updated in update Farms

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get` returns a promise. You must evaluate `then()` and take the result and assign to your scope variable.

```
http.get('farmList.JSON').then(function(data) {
    $scope.farms = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.farms` for everything:

```
$scope.farms = [];
$http.get('farmList.JSON').success(function(data) {
    $scope.farms= data;
});

var updateFarms = function() {
for (i = 1; i <= $scope.farms.length; i++)
            { 
               // code to update farms
                var sFarm = myFarm[i - 1];
                //loop thru myFarm and update it
            }
};
```